# What is the best way to create a running integer id on the AppEngine data storage?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

For various reasons, I need a unique running integer id for my entities stored on the Google AppEngine. The automatically generated key sort of has this behaviour, but it doesn't start from 1 (or 0) and doesn't guarantee that the generated integer part will come from a  continuous sequence.

What would be the best way to efficiently implement this on AppEngine? Is there any support from the storage system? To add to the complexity, I might need to do this over entities from different entity groups, meaning I can't just get the highest id right now and save an entity with the next id in a transaction. Might memcache be the way to go..?

**Edit:**

I havn't yet implemented this, but to clarify on the memcache idea. I know memcache is unreliable, but in practice it probably won't lose data "too often" to hurt performance. Basically, I would have a memcache entry for the last used id, update it (somehow atomically) whenever I create a new entity and use that id. In the case of memcache not having a value for this entry, I'd get the highest id so far by doing a query on my entities sorted by the id and update memcache (unless someone else had already done so). The only problem I can see with this right now would be atomicity of the operation as a whole if the save of my new entity was also part of a transaction. Thoughts..?

Comment: This isn't going to be easy.  Memcache is unreliable. Why do you want this ID to be auto-incrementing? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: I second what @Jason said - tell us your constraints, and we'll suggest a solution.

Comment: There might be a better way, but I do have a reason for wanting integers id that are ordered by the creation time of the entity, and packed close together, ideally without any gaps at all. Without going into to much detail, I want to perform certain operation on subsets of the data identified by one or many ranges across this id where you ideally could count the number of entities a subset actually refers to just from the ranges themselves.

Answer (score 0):

If you could live without the integer part, try the uuid module (from
the standard library): http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html

That would typically give you a 36-character string, though, maybee
that's to far from what you need. But it's unique.

Comment: That's not continuous, or even monotonic.

Comment: @Jacob, if all you need is unique, it is easier to let the data store populate the ID for you.  Freed is asking for continuous numbers.